# WP7 : Change the visibility of an item in a selected listbox item

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've got a listbox with the following data template defined:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="MyTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="textblock1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Name="textblock2" Text="{Binding SurName}" />
        <StackPanel Name="extrainfo" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock Name="textblock3" Text="{Binding Address}" />
            <TextBlock Name="textblock4" Text="{Binding Phone}" />
            <TextBlock Name="textblock5" Text="{Binding Email}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The listbox :

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" />
```

The issue is the following; when the user selects an item in the listbox I want to display the additional info by setting the visibility of the stackpanel to visible.

Any idea's how to achieve this (either via xaml or c#)? I tried to alter the storyboard but I did not get very far with that approach.

Answer (score 6):

Create an `ItemContainerStyle` that has the default `ContentControl` to present the contents of the `ItemTemplate` but also has the details content defined with the `Visibility` set to `Collapsed`. Then, update the "Selected" `VisualState` so that it sets the `Visibility` of the details panel to `Visible`:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
               <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="Details">
               <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visibile"/>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
...
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl 
        x:Name="ContentContainer" 
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    <Grid x:Name="Details">
        <!-- Put the content of your details panel here. -->
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Sound promising. Could you elaborate some more on how to do this. I tried this, I get an unhandeld exception "Cannot resolve Targetname Details".

Comment: You need to add `x:Name="Details"` to an element in the control template in the `ItemContainerStyle`. I'll update the code example above to show this.

Comment: +1 Its a sound approach, could do with the Style and Template context that this Xaml belongs in being made clearer.